# How can I have access to Included Types without using Freebase API

Tags: freebase

I want to build the subtype and super type between types of Freebase.For example; the **include Types** of *US President* [freebase-link](http://www.freebase.com/government/us_president) are:

> /people/person
>
> government/politician

These two types are super types of *US President*. Since the client version of Freebase will be shut down at the end of June and I cannot use MQL query for retrieving this type of relation based on [page 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153865/is-there-a-hierarchical-representation-of-the-freebase-types) and [page2](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Included_Type). I wonder, How can I access to this specific information through *Freebase data-dumps* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, included/including type doesn't have the same semantics as sub/super type.

Second, the Freebase data model & dump is homogeneous, so the dump should include all the domain, type, and property information -- including the included type info.  I haven't checked recently to confirm it's still there, but unless they've blacklisted the `/freebase` domain, you should be able to grep for the property `/freebase/type_hints/included_types` to work out the included relationships.

To expand on the first point, the "hint" portion of the property name is indicative of its use.  The web client (used to) pay attention to it when adding additional types based on the user's requested type, but bulk load jobs or direct users of the API could do whatever they want (including omitting `/common/topic` which the web client uses to drive a lot of its behavior.